# Problem with create Dockercompose and Dockerfile. Causes "Error response from daemon"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my first dockerfile project with docker-compose. In my project I try create a docker-compose file.

**node/Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER braulio@braulioti.com.br

LABEL Description="Site Brau.io - API NodeJS"
EXPOSE 3000

RUN yum update -y \
    && yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk \
    && yum update -y \
    && yum install -y epel-release \
    && yum install -y nodejs \
    && yum install -y psmisc \
    && npm install -g forever \
    && npm install -g typescript

RUN rm -rf /etc/localtime && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East /etc/localtime

RUN mkdir -p /app

VOLUME ["/app"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build: node
    image: docker_node
    ports:
      - "8082:3000"
    container_name: "brau_io_api"
    volumes:
      - /app/brau_io/api:/app/
    command: /bin/bash
```

This project result in:

Error response from daemon: Container 65cecc8bdc923c3f596dba91fd059b8268fd390737391d4d91afa7d34325bea1 is not running

Comment: This is not a valid `docker-compose.yml` file. Or you just provided a part. Also, what is your launch command?

Comment: thanks @grapes. This is my complete docker-compose file. Could you tell me what's missing? I try `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker-compose you should create some services and you can link them. for example:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
   my_app:
      build: .
      image: my_app:1.0.0
      container_name: my_app_container
      command: ... # you can run a bash file or a command
```

I created a docker-compose with my_app service which it can create my_app image.
you can rewrite it with your node container.

---

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

Comment: thanks @Khashayar, but my problem persists. I updated my question with your sugestions. if Itry this `docker run -it --name teste -p 8082:3000 -v /app/brau_io/api:/app/ docker_node` works fine, but for docker-compose my container don't start

Answer (score 1):

I enabled the tty function in my docker-compose.yml file and works like a chaming ([See Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/cpushares-cpuquota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-macaddress-memlimit-memswaplimit-privileged-readonly-restart-shmsize-stdinopen-tty-user-workingdir)).

This is my final docker-compose.yml file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build: node
    image: docker_node
    ports:
      - "8082:3000"
    container_name: "brau_io_api"
    volumes:
      - /app/brau_io/api:/app/
    command: /bin/bash
    tty: true
```